# ¿Cómo eliminar estas horas de esta cadena usando expresiones regulares?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex

```
' \n\n¿Estáis todos bien allí?\n\n\n1:28a.m.\n\ny él tiene que ir al fútbol\n\n 2:26 a. m.\nMe he comido 10 galletas\n\n1:28 p.m.\n\nok nos vemos allí alrededor de las 6 en punto\n\n \n\nm.\n\x0c'
```

Necesito eliminar las horas pero no los números, en este caso `1:28a.m.`, `2:26 a. m.` y `1:28 p. m.`, pero podría haber más de ellos o no estar presentes en la cadena. Y la cadena debe ser:

```
' \n\n¿Estáis todos bien allí?\n\n\n\n\ny él tiene que ir al fútbol\n\n\nMe he comido 10 galletas\n\n\n\nok nos vemos allí alrededor de las 6 en punto\n\n \n\nm.\n\x0c'
```

El problema es que puede ser en cualquier momento y puede ser `a.m.` o `a. m.`  o `p. m.` o `p. m.` , y estaba teniendo problemas para armar una expresión regular que abarque todos los tiempos para eliminarlos.

entre a.m. o pm y el valor numérico puede tener o no un espacio, por ejemplo: `2:26 a.m.` y `2:26a.m.` , y en ambos casos deben validarse con la expresión regular.

Pense en usar un `.replace` pero en estos casos necesito que tanto los numeros, como los :, como tambien los indicadores del sistema horario de 12 horas se eliminen solamente en el contexto de ese patron y no de otro modo.

Aun no me estaria funcionando con esta:

```py
import re
string = ' \n\n¿Estáis todos bien allí?\n\n\n1:28a.m.\n\ny él tiene que ir al fútbol\n\n 2:26 a. m.\nMe he comido 10 galletas\n\n1:28 p.m.\n\nok nos vemos allí alrededor de las 6 en punto\n\n \n\nm.\n\x0c'

newstring = re.sub(r'[0-9]+\s*:\s*[0-9]+', '', string)
print(newstring)
```

Comment: Hola. Genial que editaras la pregunta y añadieras el código. De esta manera no recibes puntos negativos y no termina cerrada la pregunta :)

Comment: Lo siento por eso, al principio no habia metido code porque se que la regex estaba mal y no queria meter cosas demas en la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La expresión regular para reconocer horas es:

```
\D(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*(a|p)\.\s*m\.)
```

que se lee:

```
\D         Algo distinto de digito, seguido de
\d{1,2}    uno o dos dígitos de la hora
:          seguidos de un ":"
\d{1,2}    y otro uno o dos dígitos (minutos)
\s*        Calza cero o más espacios.
(a|p)      luego debe venir una 'a' o una 'p'.
\.         seguida de un punto y
\s*        más espacios
m          y luego la letra 'm'.
\.         y otro punto.
```

La eliminación se hace aplicando `sub()`.

#### Demo

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"\D(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*(a|p)\.\s*m\.)")

texto = ' \n\n¿Estáis todos bien allí?\n\n\n1:28a.m.\n\ny él tiene que ir al fútbol\n\n 2:26 a. m.\nMe he comido 10 galletas\n\n1:28 p.m.\n\nok nos vemos allí alrededor de las 6 en punto\n\n \n\nm.\n\x0c'
texto = patron.sub('', texto)
print(texto)
```

produce:

```
¿Estáis todos bien allí?




y él tiene que ir al fútbol

 
Me he comido 10 galletas



ok nos vemos allí alrededor de las 6 en punto

 

m.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!